# Python closures using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I saw this below piece of code in a tutorial and wondering how it works.
Generally, the lambda takes a input and returns something but here it does not take anything and still it works.

```
    >>> for i in range(3):
...     a.append(lambda:i)
...
>>> a
[<function <lambda> at 0x028930B0>, <function <lambda> at 0x02893030>, <function
 <lambda> at 0x028930F0>]
```

Comment: That depends on how you define "works." What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

`lambda:i` defines the constant function that returns `i`.

Try this:

```
>>> f = lambda:3
>>> f()
```

You get the value 3.

But there's something more going on.  Try this:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> g = lambda:a
>>> g()
```

gives you `4`.  But after `a = 5`, `g()` returns `5`.  Python functions "remember" the environment in which they're executed.  This environment is called a "closure".  By modifying the data in the closure (e.g. the variable `a` in the second example) you can change the behavior of the functions defined in that closure.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `a` is a list of function objects defined in the loop.

Each of which will return `2`.

```
>>> a[0]()
2
```

To make these function objects remember `i` values sequentially you should rewrite the code to

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a.append(lambda x=i:x)
...
```

that will give you

```
>>> a[0]()
0
>>> a[1]()
1
>>> a[2]()
2
```

but in this case you get side effect that allows you to not to use remembered value

```
>>> a[0](42)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it works".  It appears that it doesn't work at all.  In the case you have presented, `i` is a global variable.  It changes every time the loop iterates, so after the loop, `i == 2`.  Now, since each lambda function simply says `lambda:i` each function call will simply return the most recent value of `i`.  For example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> for i in range(3):
    a.append(lambda:1)
>>> print a[0]()
2
>>> print a[1]()
2    
>>> print a[2]()
```

In other words, this does not likely do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` defines an anonymous inline function. These functions are limited compared to the full functions you can define with `def` - they can't do assignments, and they just return a result. However, you can run into interesting issues with them, as defining an ordinary function inside a loop is not common, but `lambda` functions are often put into loops. This can create closure issues.

The following:

```
>>> a = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a.append(lambda:i)
```

adds three functions (which are first-class objects in Python) to `a`. These functions return the value of `i`. However, they use the definition of `i` as it existed at the end of the loop. Therefore, you can call any of these functions:

```
>>> a[0]()
2
>>> a[1]()
2
>>> a[2]()
2
```

and they will each return `2`, the last iteration of the `range` object. If you want each to return a different number, use a default argument:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     a.append(lambda i=i:i)
```

This will forcibly give each function an `i` as it was at that specific point during execution.

```
>>> a[0]()
0
>>> a[1]()
1
>>> a[2]()
2
```

Of course, since we're now able to pass an argument to that function, we can do this:

```
>>> b[0](5)
5
>>> b[0](range(3))
range(0, 3)
```

It all depends on what you're planning to do with it.